# custom post type display by category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a CPT called "Blog" and I want to show the content in a category, but n does not appear in my topic.

[image]

- Here I have created an entry in my CPT and assigned the category "Champioship"

[image]

- Now I go to my Page - Page Builder and select the category I want to show

[image]

- Result: Entries created with my CPT do not appear

My CPT code:

```
<?php

// Register Custom Post Type
function blog_post_type() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Blogs', 'Post Type General Name', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Blog', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Blog', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Blog', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Archivo blog', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Atributos recetas', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Blog padre:', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'Todas', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Agregar nueva', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Agregar', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'Nueva', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Editar', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Actualizar', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'Ver blog', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'Ver blog', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Buscar receta', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'No encontrado', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No encontrado en la papelera', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Imagen detacada', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Asignar imagen destacada', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remover imagen', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Usar como imagen detacada', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insertar', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Subir', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Lista', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Navegación', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Fitro', 'Kingsclub' ),
  );
  $rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => 'blog',
    'with_front'            => true,
    'pages'                 => true,
    'feeds'                 => true,
  );
  $args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Blog', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Contenido de blog', 'Kingsclub' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'comments', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-aside',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,    
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'show_in_rest'          => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'blog_post_type', $args );


}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_post_type');
```

**This is part of the page_blog.php file where it shows the result**

```
<article <?php post_class($blog_classes); ?>>
                    <?php if($image_url <> ""){?>
                        <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" alt=""></a></figure>
                    <?php }?>
                    <div class="text">
                    <?php 
                        if($px_node->var_pb_blog_view == 'blog-medium'){
                              $before_cat = "<ul class='post-options blog-medium-options'><li>";
                                $categories_list = get_the_term_list ( get_the_id(), 'category', $before_cat, ', ', '</li></ul>' );
                                if ( $categories_list ){
                                    printf( __( '%1$s', 'Kingsclub'),$categories_list );
                                }
                        }
                    ?>
                      <h2 class="pix-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?> - PRONOSTICOS, APUESTAS, PREDICCION</a></h2>
                         <?php 
                             px_get_the_excerpt($px_node->var_pb_blog_excerpt,false);
                            wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'Kingsclub' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) );
                           ?>
                        <div class="blog-bottom">
                             <?php 
                            if($px_node->var_pb_blog_view <> 'blog-medium'){
                                px_posted_on(true,false,false,false,true,false);
                            }
                            ?>
                             <?php if($px_node->var_pb_blog_view =="blog-large"){?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btnreadmore btn pix-bgcolrhvr"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><?php if($px_theme_option["trans_switcher"] == "on") {  _e("LEER MÁS",'Kingsclub'); }else{  echo $px_theme_option["trans_read_more"];}?></a>
                            <?php } ?>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Please include the code that displays the content where you want the category to show, Also, why did you undo the changes that added the images into the question? It makes it easier for us to understand without having to open lots of separate links.

Comment: Yes, true. I have already uploaded the other part of the missing code